# Android ListView Recycler freaking out, or do I fail?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a custom listview that is populated using a row.xml file.  Each row contains two TextViews and an ImageView.  I populate the TextView from a JSON file (but this works fine, so I think you can safely ignore this), and I populate the ImageView based on SharedPreferences...which is where the problem lies.

Basically the logic is this: Someone clicks on a row in the listview, if the associated activity is completed successfully, I inform SharedPreferences and then, once the user returns to the list, a switch/case reads the SharedPreferences file and updates the ImageView in that specific row, to display a green icon.  If the user fails the Activity, the ImageView in that row displays a red icon.  A blue icon is displayed next to the first uncompleted activity in the list.

I do this by running a switch/case command for the SharedPreferences in the View formation loop.

So...my problem: I open the list, everything works fine.  The list displays a single blue icon, as expected.  When I scroll down, I see another blue icon further down...which shouldn't be there.  OK, you're thinking "you F**ked up your coding".  However - when I scroll back up the list, I see the blue icon has now 'jumped' from the expected list item, to the one below.  I scroll back down again and I see the blue icon has multiplied - there are now two of them in two different rows, where none existed before.  So I completed a task.  A green icon appears where it should.  I scroll up and down a few times and suddenly there are 3-4 green icons next to different list rows.

My only guess is that the recycler is freaking out.  Am I right?  Is there something I can do to fix this?  I tried being sneaky - I used 'setVisibility-GONE' for rows that where imageview is not needed...after some scrolling though, there it is - it's annoying greenness lighting up the row it cannot possibly be in.  Here's my source code:

```
public class MainList extends ListActivity {
static SharedPreferences statusSettings;
String jsonString;
static JSONObject json;
static JSONArray arrayTest;
static int bob = 3;


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try {
        JSONObject e = arrayTest.getJSONObject(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("clientName", e.getString("proj_name"));
        intent.putExtra("clientAddress", e.getString("c_address"));
        intent.putExtra("clientComments", e.getString("comments"));
        intent.putExtra("clientOrder", e.getString("order"));
        intent.setClass(MainList.this, ClientDetails.class);
        MainList.this.startActivity(intent);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("JSON", "Problem creating object from array!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayTest.length();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlist, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMainIcon);
            holder.textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainName);
            holder.textAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainAddress);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

        JSONObject e;
        try {
            e = arrayTest.getJSONObject(position);
            holder.textName.setText(e.getString("proj_name"));
            holder.textAddress.setText(e.getString("c_address"));   

            switch (statusSettings.getInt(e.getString("order"), 0)){
                case 1:
                    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(bob == 3){
                        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_delivery);
                        bob = 5;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delivered_icon);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.undelivered_icon);
                    break;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("JSON", "Couldn't put one of JSON arrays into object");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    jsonString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("jsonString");
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        arrayTest = json.getJSONArray("client_list");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("JSON", "Couldn't create the JSON Array");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    bob = 3;        
    statusSettings = getSharedPreferences("status", 0);

    setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
}


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

/edit: in case you need it - here is the row.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMainName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainIcon"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMainAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Updated Switch/Case (courtesy of Brigham)...still using a half-assed solution with the bob variable though.  At least everything now works as it should!:

```
switch (statusSettings.getInt(e.getString("order"), 0)){
                case 1:
                    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(bob.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("do it") || bob.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getString("proj_name"))){

                        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_delivery);
                        bob = e.getString("proj_name");
                    }else{
                        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delivered_icon);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.undelivered_icon);
                    break;
                default:
                    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: does the convertView comes as null each time? have you tried to get rid of the ViewHolder and use a RelativeLayout directly and return it? does your statusSettings.getInt(e.getString("order"), 0) return you different values all the time? and how does your row.xml look like? thank you.

Comment: Not sure about convertView, nor have I tried RelativeLayout.  I'm still a noob in learning so I'd need to look up how that stuff is done.  As for  statusSettings.getInt(e.getString("order") - no - it only returns 4 values.  1 = "not done".  2 = "The previous activity was done, but I have not been done".  3 = "done successfully" and 4 = "task failed".
This is also the reason for bob - as I only want one case 2: to show a blue icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `case 2`, you only set the image if `bob == 3`. You should add an else clause and make the image invisible when `bob != 3`. You should also make sure to set the icon to visible before the switch statement since most of your cases require it to be visible.

You should also consider adding a default case to your switch statement.

```
        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        switch (statusSettings.getInt(e.getString("order"), 0)){
            case 1:
                holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(bob == 3){
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_delivery);
                    bob = 5;
                } else {
                    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delivered_icon);
                break;
            case 4:
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.undelivered_icon);
                break;
            default:
                holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to have fixed a lot.  The Green and Red icons (delivered and undelivered) work fine now - no jumping around.  The blue vanishes however.  I am assuming that the view is created dynamically by the recycler as I scroll, so it sees bob=3, shows next_delivery icon, changes bob to 5 and then once it destroys the view it never shows the icon again, as bob is no longer 3.  I need to rethink my logic and make something serious instead of that half-assed solution.  Thanks man.

I still can't figure out why the green and red icons were multiplying though...it's doing my head in!

Comment: Right...I fixed my half-assed solution so it is now a more complex, but no more dignified, half-assed solution.  The app is working as intended now - thanks very much!

Comment: Basically, when you use recycled views, you need to make sure that you reset every field in the view, otherwise you'll end up with artifacts of an older view popping up like you were seeing.

Comment: Ah gotcha - so recycler doesn't bother deleting the values of the views it's recycling.  I guess that makes sense...if you are using the same values (such as background, images, etc), it can save time that way...plus, why would it waste time deleting stuff when you can do it yourself if you need to - it's a pretty busy little class.  Thanks for the help - it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to disable your recycler.  You may not want to do that but all you have to do is remove the convertView==null and it's else statement.  This will stop the artifacts from recycling views.